# Гласная после суффикса Ц

Tags: морфология

Какое правило регулирует окончания существительных после суффикса **Ц**. Следующие существительные все среднего рода, но в одних окончание **е**, а в других **о**.

> сено - сенц**о**, село - сельц**о**, копыто -
> копытц**е**,  корыто - корытц**е**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**§ 6.** Написание ***о*** или ***е*** после ***ц*** в русских словах определяется следующими правилами:

1. В слогах ударяемых пишется **о** или ***е*** в соответствии с произношением…

2… При отсутствии ударения в суффиксах и окончаниях всегда пишется ***е***, например: *полотенц**е**, пальц**е**м…*

http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=gl&text=19_1

**См. также:**

http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=20#pp20

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=38#pp38

Comment: Не все классики знают это правило :  
>И. А. Гончаров. Обрыв (1869)
Повара и кухарки, тоже заслышав звон ключей, принимались ― за нож, за уполовник или за метлу, а Кирюша быстро отскакивал от Матрены к воротам, а Матрена шла уже в хлев, будто через силу **тащила корытцо**, прежде нежели бабушка появилась.